# How can one deploy a large model onto a GPU using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory, large-language-model

I aimed to fine-tune the Google's open source, Gemma model (7b)(https://blog.google/technology/developers/gemma-open-models/) on my NVIDIA 3050 ti GPU with 4GB of dedicated RAM. However, upon downloading and running everything, I encountered a resource exhaustion exception right after loading the model config file.

There are some libraries available, such as (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wmlce/1.6.0?topic=gsmf-getting-started-tensorflow-large-model-support-tflms-v2) for tf 2.1, which help address this issue by segmenting memory and loading only the necessary parts. Unfortunately, it seems these libraries haven't been maintained for quite some time.

Is there any alternative approach that could assist me in loading the model on my laptop?

Additionally, I tried `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth` and setting a memory limit.

Comment: You can take a look into model quantization, especially 4-bit. [On Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/google/gemma-7b) is an example how to use 4-bit quantization with this model (search for `Using 4-bit precision`).

Comment: Thank you! I'll certainly look into it. However, addressing this will only resolve the current issue. What if Google scales up the model to 14 billion parameters? How would I be able to deploy that model? I'm aiming to address the problem comprehensively from its core.

Comment: 7 billion parameters (at 32-bit) take around 26GB just for the model itself. This doesn't take into account the activations you will have to store when running the model, gradients during training, etc. I realize this is not the answer you are looking for (and I hope someone else can point you in a useful direction, because I can't), but you will have an _extremely_ hard time doing LLMs (most of deep learning actually, but especially LLMs) with 4GB of RAM.

Comment: The only other "solution" I found is https://huggingface.co/blog/lyogavin/airllm. But this only talks about inference. You could try to combine this with a forward step where you load the layers, compute the gradients wrt. this layer, and move on, but I'm not sure it's possible. You still need all the gradients for the LLM. I think xdurch0 is right, it will be really hard.